# PHP: Simple HTML DOM Parser : content of <meta property="article:publisher"

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get the content of the meta tag "article:publisher" with the php code

`$html = str_get_html($str);
$ret = $html->find('meta[property=article:publisher]');
$value = $ret->content;
echo "publisher val = ".$value[0];`

can anyone see what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

If the meta tag is something like:

```
<meta property='article:publisher' content="Article Publisher Name" />
```

This works for me:

```
$html = str_get_html($str);
$value = $html->find('meta[property=article:publisher]', 0)->content;
echo "publisher val = ".$value;
```

Or you can get the `$value` in two steps if you wish:

```
$ret = $html->find('meta[property=article:publisher]');
$value = $ret[0]->content;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$html = str_get_html($str);
$ret = $html->find('meta[property=article:publisher]'); 
$value = $ret[0]->plaintext; 
echo "publisher val = ".$value;
```